# Copy the LONGBLOB file from one table to another using PHP

Tags: php, database

```
//SELECT DB
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database");

//FETCH DATA FROM TABLE1
$check= mysqli_query($con, "select * from user_info_tbl where username = '$user_check' ") or die(mysqli_error($con));

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($check); 
$username = $row["username"];
$picture = $row["picture"]; //my way of getting the blob file to table1

$content = addslashes($_POST["content"]); //this is from an input tag

//INSERTING DATA TO TABLE2 INCLUDING THE BLOB FILE
$query1="INSERT INTO postings (prof_pic,user_name, content)
        VALUES ('$picture','$username','$content')";
```

This is my table1

```
|ID    |username     |    picture
+------+-------------+-----------------+
|1     |user1        | [BLOB -7.3 KiB] |
|2     |user2        | [BLOB -2.4 KiB] |
|3     |user3        | [BLOB -6.0 KiB] |
```

This is my table2

```
|ID    |prof_pic     | username  |  content
+------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
|1     |             | user1     |this is my post
|2     |             | user2     |hello world
|3     |             | user2     |lets go
```

But only the username and content are being inserted into the table2. I want to get the 'picture' on table1 to copy on 'prof_pic' on table2, where table1.username = table2.username

Can someone help me, getting the blob file to insert it to another table. 
Thanks in advance.

PS. Im just a beginner. Sorry for messy codes.

Comment: _"Line 23 which is the $query1."_ I don't think it is. The warning is coming from a call to the function `file_get_contents()`, which doesn't appear anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: Sorry, i just edited my question.

Comment: Could you provide us your table structure?

Comment: `INSERT INTO postings (prof_pic, user_name, content) VALUES ((SELECT picture FROM user_info_tbl WHERE username = ... LIMIT 1), ...)`

Comment: @Cobra_Fast thanks for helping, but it also doesn't work. :(